# Нужна ли запятая перед "если": "в том числе если..."

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая перед "если"?

*Стоимость подписки не подлежит возврату, в том числе если клиент не воспользовался её преимуществами.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*В том числе* — союз в составе присоединительного оборота, и не может быть от него обособлен.

Пример gramota от справочной службы русского языка: «...Изучает материалы, в том числе используя и общедоступные источники информации».